The infinity category of dg-categories is bicomplete
We can define the $\infty$-category of dg-categories $dgCat_\infty$ as the definition of the $\infty$-category of $\infty$-categories which given gy the section.3 of J.Lurie "Higher Topos Theory".
That is, objects of $dgCat_\infty$ are (small) dg-categories and $Map_{dgCat_\infty}(C,D) := N_{dg}(Fun(C,D))^{\simeq}$, where $N_{dg}$ is the dg-nerve and $(-)^{\simeq}$ is the maximal sub Kan complex.
Lemma 1.3.1 in "NOTES ON GEOMETRIC LANGLANDS: GENERALITIES ON DG CATEGORIES" by Gaitsgory implies that $dgCat_\infty$ is bicomplete.
I do not understand this proof. He wrote "This is done in HTT section 5.5.3" , but I cannot make sure this is correct.

Is it the same as $\operatorname{Perf}(\mathbb Z)$-modules in the $\infty$-category $\operatorname{Cat}^{\operatorname{Ex}}$ of small stable $\infty$-categories? Then it follows directly from the latter being presentable.
